# Adding an existing Contact to an existing Contact Group?

Tags: xero-api

I'm using the Xero-NetStandard wrapper and trying to add an existing contact to an existing contact group:

```
var newContact = GetContact(contactId),
var group = _xero.GetContactGroupAsync(accessToken, tenantId, new Guid(GroupGuid)).Result._ContactGroups.First();
newContact.ContactGroups.Add(group);
```

When debugging, I can see that both newContact and group are both successfully populated with data from the call.

Do I need to do something further after the .Add call to persist the change?